# proof that $\frac{m^a}{2}+\frac{m}{2}-1$ is not a prime number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm having trouble proving the following:

> If $m$ is an even number, $m\ge4$ and $a$ is an integer, $a\ge2$ then  $$\frac{m^a}{2}+\frac{m}{2}-1$$  is not a prime number.

Usually, in this type of exercises, someone has to show that the number can be written as a product of more than two expressions but whatever I've tried doesn't work...Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

$${m^a\over 2}+{m\over 2}-1 = {m^a+m-2\over 2} = {m^a-1 + m-1\over 2} $$

$$= {(m-1)(m^{a-1} + ...+m+1)+(m-1)\over 2} $$

$$= \underbrace{(m-1)}_{=a}\underbrace{m^{a-1} + ...+m+2\over 2}_{=b} $$

Clearly $a>1$ and $b>1$ and $b$ is an integer, since $m$ is even.

So, the number is product of two numbers both $>1$, so it is not a prime.

Comment: so my number is divided by 2, therefore my number is not a prime... right? thank you!

Comment: No, your number is product of two numbers both >1, so it is not a prime.

Comment: any number divided by 2 (except 2 itself) is not a prime number

Comment: @hlx55555 Try $m=4$ and $a=2$. The number doesn't have to be even.

Comment: @yurnero ok, now I see what you both mean... the mistake I made was looking at the numerator and not the number as a whole. When the numerator is divided by two, the quotient is not necessarily an even number

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$m^a+m-2$$ is divisible by $m-1$ and is even as $m^a+m=m(1+m^{a-1})$ is even for integer $m$

Comment: wow, such quick response!! Thank you so much! I can't believe it was such a simple answer...

Comment: @hlx55555 "I begin to think, Watson," said Holmes, "that I make a mistake in explaining. 'Omne ignotum pro magnifico,' you know, and my poor little reputation, such as it is, will suffer shipwreck if I am so candid" --- Arthur Conan Doyle in *Red Headed League* (1891).